# Оформление предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли оформить следующее предложение так: 
"В лес вообще мы ходили часто: зимой - на лыжах, летом – просто так".

Изначально там все было через запятую: 
"В лес вообще мы ходили часто, зимой на лыжах, летом просто так".

Comment: Можно и так. А вообще убрать нельзя?

Comment: Что убрать и зачем?

Comment: Слово "вообще". Оно здесь вносит чисто разговорный оттенок (ещё сильнее было бы "вообще мы в лес ходили часто") и по-моему, совсем ненужный.

И вдобавок непонятно, надо ли обосабливать это "вообще".

Comment: У слова "вообще" есть не только оттенок, но и вполне конкретный смысл, который должен следовать из текста.

Comment: Всё понятно, обосабливать не надо, это не вводное слово.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемый вариант: "В лес мы вообще  ходили часто: зимой на лЫжах, летом просто тАк".

Пояснение

1. При таком оформлении отсутствует параллельная интонация и не ставится тире.
2. Слово "вообще" перенесено, чтобы оно не стояло между подлежащим и сказуемым и не провоцировало обособление.

Для сравнения: "В лес мы вообще  ходили часто: зимОй - на лЫжах, лЕтом - просто тАк" (параллельная интонация).

**Дополнительные примеры**

В спальне две маленькие двери: справа в кабинет, а слева  в коридор.

Трое ворот вело из города: одни – на полдень, другие – на север, третьи – прямо в Орду.

Comment: Что такое "на лыжАх"?

Comment: А теперь правильно?

Answer (score 0):

Да, здесь предпочтительно тире. Тире ставится при параллелизме конструкций( частей предложения): ***Усердный*** в бригаде - ***клад, ленивый*** - тяжелая обуза. ( Д.Э. Розенталь. Справочник- практикум). То же и у вас. 
 <...> зимой - на лыжах, летом - просто - так.

Comment: Летом - что? Шутите что ли?

Comment: Вас интересует постановка тире? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Да, но там не было слова "простак".

Comment: Опечатка. Да, тире возможно.